# When are two given lines parallel and identical?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

So I need a bit help with lines. I am considering 2 cases,

1. When they are parallel and
2. When they are completely same, same coordinates, everything, one on top of another.

This is what I think how it is, please tell me if I'm right, and correct me if I'm wrong.

1. When are they parallel, for example if I have two lines
   \begin{align*}
   y_1&=m_1x+n_1,\\
   y_2&=m_2x+n_2.
   \end{align*}
   and if $m_1 = m_2$ regardless of $n_1$ and $n_2$ they are parallel ?
2. When they are same (one on top of another)
   \begin{align*}
   y_1&=m_1x+n_1,\\
   y_2&=m_2x+n_2.
   \end{align*}
   $m_2=m_1$ and $n_1=n_2$?

Image:
[a) Parallel b) Same lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWR0n.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. If $m_1=m_2$ the two lines are parallel, and if moreover $n_1=n_2$ the two lines are identical. On the left-hand side of your equation, you can just write $y$ instead of $y_1$ and $y_2$ (like you do with $x$).

Comment: haven't finished the sentence... anyway if i got it tight, m is for direction and n is for position of the line

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to think about it

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Good work.

**FYI:** If you want to include vertical lines as well, then the lines will have the form
\begin{align*}
a_1 x + b_1 y &= c_1 \\
a_2 x + b_2 y &= c_2,
\end{align*}
where we assume $a_1^2 + b_1^2 = 1$ and $a_2^2 + b_2^2 = 1$.
The two lines will be

- **parallel** if $a_1 b_2 = b_1 a_2$; and
- **identical** if $a_1 = a_2$, $b_1 = b_2$, $c_1 = c_2$.

Answer (score 0):

they are parallel when their slopes m1 and m2 are equal, y-intercept n1 is not equal n2
              y1=x+1
              y1=x-1    slope =1 for both ; yint1=n1=1; yint2=n2=-1

same  y1=x+1; y2=x+1 same equation